# Change default username in LiveCD

Tags: live-usb, custom-distributions, username, live-environment

I've created a custom Ubuntu image for myself using UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit).

My question is: when I boot the image as a LiveCD or LiveUSB, it automatically creates and logs you in to the user `ubuntu`. Is it possible to change this default username to something else, like `myname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username is stored on the live DVD in ...

```
edit/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper
```

The hostname is in there too. The password is in ...

```
edit/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/10adduser
```

If UCK does not allow you to change it from the gui you will need to chroot the ISO yourself and do it manually. More on that in [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679) and on the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) (the part about gconf is invalid nowadays; but the other information still looks valid).

Comment: It seems like changing the username in the `USERNAME=casper` line  in the `remaster-root/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper` file does not have any effect. I tried this in v16.04. In fact, the `casper` file has only a single "ubuntu" word in a comments. Am I missing something?

Comment: It has been a while I did anything with this but what is `remaster-root` in there?  as far as I know it should still be `edit/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper`

Comment: remaster-root is the directory (as far as I understand) where the UCK contains the open ISO. I could not find the `edit` directory. Maybe it changed with the version change.